# Android add day to calendar with for loop

Tags: android, arrays, database, calendar

I have an array populated with the id of a database table in ascending order. Now within a list fetch more data to another database table that has a field with the same records in the preceding table. An example

int [] id_nome_op; // for example, contains data (1,2,3)

Now I want to compare this array with data taken from another table (the column for comparison has a field with the same values of the array), then the first match if they are equal, I want to set the date on the calendar today.

When the value changes I want to set the date with TODAY + 1
When the value changes again I want to set the date with TODAY + 2 and so on. I hope I explained myself:

```
@Override
public List<WkVvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final String strDate = simpleFormat.format(calendarioFooter.getTime());


SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
        String tabella_op = "SELECT m.id_altra_tabella .....ORDER BY ASC ";
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(tabella_op, null);
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        startTime = (Calendar) calendarioFooter.clone();
        id_altra_tabella = cur.getInt(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < id_nome_op.length; i++) {
            if (id_altra_tabella == id_nome_op[i]) {
                startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
            } else if (id_altra_tabella> id_nome_op[i]) {
                startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
        }
..
..
..
}
```

thi is my code, but I do not get the desired result

**EDIT:**
I try to explain:
if for example, the array (int [] id_nome_op;) has three values (1,2,3) and the data collected in the list are the same, that is, (1,2,3), with the loop I want to do this :
when (id_nome_op) and (id_altra_tabella) are equal to the first value (in this case 1) I have set the calendar with today's date. When this value changes (for example 2) I need to add to the calendar today's date + 1. When changes again (eg 3) I need to add to the calendar today +2, and so on.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Simplify your Question to the essential core of your technical issue. We are not here to write your app for you. As it stands, your Question is difficult to understand, if not unintelligible. See [*MCVE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want the functionality of the .roll() method instead of the .add() method.  Roll will adjust the month and year as well as the day.  Add will not.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Edit: My description is backwards...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't completely understand the problem you are having.  You say you don't get the desired result.  What result do you get?  How does it differ from your expected result?

Comment: I think I understand what you're wanting to do.  But what result do you get?  You say it is not the desired result, but it's not clear what you get in place of the desired result.

Comment: what I get is that the days are not added as needed. That is, the first record that matches must assign the current date, when it changes, it must assign today's date +1, when changes still must assign today's date +2. I think the problem is the for loop. Thanks for your help

Comment: What your loop is doing is: on each entry, if the record matches the day is set to 9, if id_altra_tabella is larger it adds 1 to the day.  If  id_altra_tabella is smaller it does nothing.  This comparison is being done for each element in the array for each record in your table.   If the last element in id_nome_op matches then the day will get set back to 9 regardless of any previous increments.  From your description I do not believe this is the behavior you intend.